# Replace special characters from all elements and attributes data in xslt 1.0

Tags: xpath, xslt-1.0

I have this xslt through which i am trying to replace special characters from an XML file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>
    <xsl:variable name="E" select="'ë'"/>
    <xsl:variable name="U" select="'ü'"/>
    <xsl:variable name="Euro" select="'€'"/>
    <xsl:template match="node() | @*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node() | @*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="text()">
        <xsl:value-of select="translate(translate(translate(.,$E, 'e'),$U,'u'),$Euro,'&#8364;')"/>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

But this is only working for all xml elements but not for attributes. Can someone advise how this can work for each and every element and attributes values?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>
  <xsl:variable name="E" select="'ë'"/>
  <xsl:variable name="U" select="'ü'"/>
  <xsl:variable name="Euro" select="'€'"/>  


  <xsl:template match="*">    
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:for-each select="@*">
        <xsl:attribute name="{name(.)}">
          <xsl:value-of select="translate(translate(translate(.,$E, 'e'),$U,'u'),$Euro,'&#8364;')"/>
        </xsl:attribute>
      </xsl:for-each>
      <xsl:apply-templates></xsl:apply-templates>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="text()">    
    <xsl:value-of select="translate(translate(translate(.,$E, 'e'),$U,'u'),$Euro,'&#8364;')"/>
  </xsl:template>  
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: 1) * - all elements
2) copy this element
3) copy all it's attributes and translate it's content
4) apply templates